# Caching for Neo4j user-defined procedures

Tags: database, caching, graph, neo4j, relational

I am current running a comparative experiment for some algorithms running on top of a relational database (PostgreSQL) and a graph one (Neo4j).
I implemented my algorithm as a user-defined procedure for Neo4j, but it doesn't look like it performs any caching out-of-box.
Is there a way to configure caching for user-defined procedures in Neo4j?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement the caching yourself, if it's relevant for your use case and you have something to cache: probably something not related to the transaction, so no nodes or relationships; Neo4j ids are tricky, since they can be reused, so it's probably best to only cache them for a short duration, or not at all. Application-level ids would be fine, as would beans composed of strings or scalar types.

Suppose you have this procedure defined:

```java
public class MyProcedure {
    @Context
    public GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Procedure
    public Stream<MyBean> doSomething(@Name("uuid") String uuid) {
         int count = 0;
         // ...
         return Stream.of(new MyBean(count));
    }

    public static class MyBean {
        public int count;

        public MyBean(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }
    }
}
```

You can add some simple caching using a `ConcurrentMap`:

```java
public class MyProcedure {
    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Collection<MyBean>> CACHE =
            new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Context
    public GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Procedure
    public Stream<MyBean> doSomething(@Name("uuid") String uuid) {
         Collection<MyBean> result = CACHE.computeIfAbsent(uuid,
                 k -> doSomethingCacheable(k).collect(Collectors.toList()));
         return result.stream();
    }

    private Stream<MyBean> doSomethingCacheable(String uuid) {
         int count = 0;
         // ...
         return Stream.of(new MyBean(count));
    }

    public static class MyBean {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that you can't cache a `Stream` as it can only be consumed once, so you have to consume it yourself by collecting into an `ArrayList` (you can also move the `collect` inside the method, change the return type to `Collection<MyBean>` and use a method reference). If the procedure takes more than one argument, you'll need to create a proper class for the composite key (immutable if possible, with correct `equals` and `hashCode` implementation). *The restrictions that apply to cacheable values also apply to the keys.*

This is an eternal, unbounded cache. If you need more features (expiration, maximum size), I suggest you use a real cache implementation, such as [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Cache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) (or [`LoadingCache`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html)) or Ben Manes' [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was something out-of-the-box so I could compare the caching implementations as well, but will try one off the libraries you suggested instead of the dump one I was making myself.